# Spring: Custom locale resolver

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm using a custom implemented `ResourceBundleMessageSource`:

```
public class CustomResourceBundleMessageSource
    extends org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource { //... }
```

Shortly, it's looking for message codes into resource bundles according to current locale.

```
public final String getMessage(String code) {
    return getMessage(code, null, null, getCurrentLocale());
}


public Locale getCurrentLocale() {
    Locale locale = ThreadLocalHolder.get(LOCALE_PROPERTY_NAME, Locale.class);

    if (locale == null) {           
        locale = (defaultLocale==null)?Locale.getDefault():defaultLocale;
    }

    return locale;
}
```

As you can see it's picking current locale from a `ThreadLocalHolder` class.

So, I'd like to resolve `Accept-Language` request header and set this value on this `ThreadLocalHolder`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you need a custom `MessageSource` for that? Spring already provides everything out-of-the-box to all of that. Looks like you are working around the framework instead of using the framework. Instead of your `getCurrentLocale` method (or as the implementation) do `LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()` instead. Then it will just work as the default `LocaleResolver` is the `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver`.

Comment: My boss, my friend.